# How long can a Bard sing?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

Specifically, when using [Inspire Courage.](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/bard.htm#inspireCourage) The entry for it doesn't mention anything about needing concentration, nor does it list a duration. All of the other entries seem to have their own time limits. [Bardic Music](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/bard.htm#bardicMusic) doesn't seem to have a base duration.

Can I keep singing until I go blue in the face, or is there a limit somewhere? Because I remember it being limited to one minute per level or so, but it doesn't say.

Comment: If you're looking to impose some limits, there may be some guidance under Forced March (while talking about walking does speak to the fact people can't do something forever=)).  2 cents.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no hard-and-fast limit.<sup>1</sup> Warforged and undead bards can sing indefinitely, seeing as they need neither breathe nor sleep.

For more biologically-limited bards, the limit is whatever makes sense to the table. In this, bardic music is just like all kinds of other not-specifically-strenuous activity: the rules just don’t cover it. Arcane spellcasters *need* sleep, but there are no rules for staying up for other classes. Running or marching eventually tire you out and force you to stop, but a simple leisurely walk has no rules for when you cannot do that anymore. And yet we know that all humanoids require sleep (or trance) and cannot do such activities indefinitely. So the table has to draw the line somewhere. Bardic music is the same.

1. <sup>Note that this is true of all bardic music **except Countersong, Fascinate, and Inspire Competence**, which require your concentration and are limited to 10 rounds, 1 round/level, and 2 minutes, respectively. Song of Freedom has an instantaneous effect after 1 minute of concentration; nothing says you can’t keep singing after that, it just doesn’t do anything.</sup>